# plotting multiple columns in R using geom_point

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, geom-point

i have a data frame that looks like this :
[image]

total-36 columns.

data sample code :

```
df <-
  
  structure(
    list(
      Bacteroidaceae = c(
        0,
        0.10944999,
        0.104713314,
        0.125727668,
        0.124136247,
        0.005155911,
        0.005072778,
        0.010231826,
        0.010188139
        
      ),
      Christensenellaceae = c(
        0,
        0.009910731,
        0.010131195,
        0.009679938,
        0.01147601,
        0.010484508,
        0.008641566,
        0.010017172,
        0.010741488
        
      ),
      
      treatment = c(
        "Original Sample1",
        "Original Sample2",
        "Original Sample3",
        "Original Sample4",
        "treatment1_1",
        "treatment1_2",
        "treatment1_3",
        "treatment1_4"
      )
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-8L)
  )
```

what i wish to do is to creat plots for all the columns in the data so evey column would have 2 plots : one for treatment1 and one for the original sample in total 72 plots

for example:

[image]

same for the original sample type
i tried  using this code:

```
df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(!treatment, names_to = "taxa", values_to = "value") %>%
  dplyr::filter(str_detect(treatment, "Treatment1")) %>%
   for (i in columns(df)){
    )
  ggplot(aes(x = treatment, y = value, color = taxa),group=treatment) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean,
               geom = "line", width = 0.5)+geom_jitter(widh=0.25)
  theme_bw()}}
```

but it didnt work .
is there any other way ?

thank you

Comment: After you reshape to 'long' , what is the `for (i in columns(df)){
    )` in the code doing.  Is it a typo?

Comment: Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval.
Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument?

Comment: The syntax is not correct i.e.  `for` loop placement seems to be incorrect

Comment: what do you mean by "for loop placement seems to be incorrect"?

Comment: `df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(!treatment, names_to = "taxa", values_to = "value") %>%
  dplyr::filter(str_detect(treatment, "treatment1")) %>% ggplot(aes(x = treatment, y = value, color = taxa), group = treatment) + geom_point() +  stat_summary(fun.y = mean,
               geom = "line", width = 0.5)+geom_jitter(widh=0.25)
  theme_bw()` this code seems to work

Comment: Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  ggplot(aes(x = treatment, y = value, color = taxa), group = treatment) + geom_point() +  
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean,geom = "line", width = 0.5)+geom_jitter(widh=0.25) theme_bw"

Comment: but how does it loop over al the columns with out the for loof?

Comment: I forgot the `+` before the `theme_bw()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-treatment) %>% 
  mutate(plot = ifelse(str_detect(treatment, "Original"), 
                       "Original Sample", 
                       "Treatment 1"),
         treatment = str_extract(treatment, "\\d+$")) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  group_split() %>% 
  map(~.x %>% ggplot(aes(x = factor(treatment), y = value, color = factor(name))) +
         geom_point() +
         facet_wrap(~plot) +
         labs(x = "Treatment", y = "Value", color = "Taxa") +
         theme_bw())
```

This produces two plots (based on the test data):

[image]

[image]

Comment: the thing is that i need to plot all the columns  in different plots so in total i will have 72 plots 2 for each column plotting all the 36 column in one plot will be too much